# Celery's task ETA is not accurate

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Celery and the [eta](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/2.0-archived/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown) feature. According the docs there's no guarantee that the task is executed at the exact time of the ETA, but some time after this.

I found to have significant lag with this and was wondering if there's a way to make it more accurate e.g. by causing the worker to poll tasks more often.

Is there some configuration or method to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same issue in the project. There is a setting "worker_timer_precision" but it does not work properly and it's been broken since long time ago.

There is an open issue in GitHub but it's important that the community gives feedback to developers. The issue is added as a milestone for 5.3.X version and it can take a lot of time before it's resolved.

Please comment in GitHub so that the developers pay attention to the issue:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4191